# C++ function to safely compare integers of different types?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, integer-overflow

Due to implicit conversion and the fact that `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` and friends return type `T`, it seems non-trivial to write a function `bool cmp(IntA a, IntB b)` that "does the right thing" to conceptually `return a < b;`. That is, if they share a common range, compare, if not, determine if `a` is less than `b` regardless of number of bits or signedness. Is there a simpler implementation than this naive one?:

```
template <typename IntA, typename IntB>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool cmp(IntA a, IntB b) noexcept {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<IntA>);
    static_assert(sizeof(IntA) <= sizeof(long long int), "We assume we can fit everything into long long");
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<IntB>);
    static_assert(sizeof(IntB) <= sizeof(long long int), "We assume we can fit everything into long long");
    if (a < 0) {
        if (b < 0) {
            return static_cast<signed long long int>(a) < static_cast<signed long long int>(b);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (b < 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return static_cast<unsigned long long int>(a) < static_cast<unsigned long long int>(b);
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aPbozGW9j

And what can we do to ensure it gets fully optimized?

Comment: What do you mean by "fully optimized"? There isn't, in practice, much code at all here.

Comment: Most compilers will do the _"correct thing"_ (integer promotion) and warn you if  they cannot (eg signed, unsigned mismatch etc).  Do you have a concrete example of the problem you are trying to fix ?  This feels link an XY-Problem.

Comment: isnt your code similar to just (modulo signdness) `bool cmp(long long a, long long b) { return a < b; }` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 your cmp would fail on `cmp(ll_min, ull_max);`. This code gets round that.

Comment: @MikeVine (modulo signdness). I am just trying to understand what the implementation is trying to solve (and how) in addition to signdness.

Comment: Its just letting you compare _any_ numbers of _any_ integral type correctly.

Comment: Code seems reasonable. I'd assume a decent compiler would optimise this thoroughly. What I would recommend is templating (with a default type) the "maximum sized integral type" that you want to support - you hardcode use of `{signed|unsigned} long long int` everywhere. Just template this out to let users decide which type they want to use.

Comment: @RichardCritten Will they? Is it defined behavior? (I'm not certain either way.) I found it easy to get tripped up by `if (b < std::numeric_limits<IntA>::max())` causing the same problem I started with. One approach is to cast everything but `uint64_t` to `int64_t` and compare, and then special-case signed vs unsigned int64 comparison.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think thats the point. They'll warn you that you have a compare with a signed/unsigned mismatch. But the above code shows that you can validly compare signed/unsigned if you're willing to have a bit of overhead. Compilers will not (and should not by default) add that overhead. However, the user may know that a signed/unsigned compare is necessary and the overhead of the above function is the right thing to do.

Comment: Right, the use case is when you want to avoid the warning but are paranoid about casting to a particular common type.

Comment: @MikeVine and many times the real error is code like `if (index < my_vector.size() - 1)` (where index is `int`) and the proposed template will just hide the problem, (the above code will not give the expected result if the vector is empty)

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes. And if you notice this is a named function which wont be used there. No one is saying this should be used everywhere theres a compare. Its a tool to use when necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use C++20, then you can use the [newly added functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) to do just this.  We now have

```
template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool cmp_equal( T t, U u ) noexcept;

template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool cmp_not_equal( T t, U u ) noexcept;

template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool cmp_less( T t, U u ) noexcept;

template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool cmp_greater( T t, U u ) noexcept;

template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool cmp_less_equal( T t, U u ) noexcept;

template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool cmp_greater_equal( T t, U u ) noexcept;
```

which

> Compare the values of two integers `t` and `u`. Unlike builtin comparison operators, negative signed integers always compare less than (and not equal to) unsigned integers: the comparison is safe against lossy integer conversion.
>
> ```
> -1 > 0u; // true
> std::cmp_greater(-1, 0u); // false
> ```
>
> It is a compile-time error if either `T` or `U` is not a signed or unsigned integer type (including standard integer type and extended integer type).

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
template <typename IntA, typename IntB>
bool cmp(IntA a, IntB b) { 
    if constexpr (std::is_signed<IntA>::value == std::is_signed<IntB>::value)
    {
        return a < b;
    }
    return a < 0 || (b >= 0 && a < b);
}
```

If both types are of the same signed-ness, then comparing them is safe. If they are not, then:

1. if `a < 0` then `b >= 0` and we return true.
2. otherwise `a >= 0`. If `b < 0` the expression will return false. If `b >= 0` then both are positive and it's safe to return `a < b`.

https://godbolt.org/z/hPKxoscKn

Answer (score 0):

Your jumping through hoops at runtime (via comparing with zero) is only necessary when the signed'ness of the inputs mismatch. So I'd recommend using `if constexpr` to help the compiler get it right in only the cases where it might be useful. Something like:

```
template <typename LargestSignedInt = long long int, typename IntA, typename IntB>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool cmp(IntA a, IntB b) noexcept {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<IntA>);
    static_assert(sizeof(IntA) <= sizeof(LargestSignedInt));
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<IntB>);
    static_assert(sizeof(IntB) <= sizeof(LargestSignedInt));

    if constexpr(sizeof(IntA) < sizeof(LargestSignedInt) && sizeof(IntB) < sizeof(LargestSignedInt))
    {
        // Both types are smaller than largest signed type supported, just use largest signed type.
        return static_cast<LargestSignedInt>(a) < static_cast<LargestSignedInt>(b);
    }

    if constexpr(std::is_signed_v<IntA> != std::is_signed_v<IntB>)
    {
        // Signedness mismatch
        if (a < 0) {
            if (b < 0) {
                return static_cast<LargestSignedInt>(a) < static_cast<LargestSignedInt>(b);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (b < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<LargestSignedInt>::type>(a) < static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<LargestSignedInt>::type>(b);
            }
        }
    }

    if constexpr(std::is_signed_v<IntA>)
    {
        // Both types are signed.
        return static_cast<LargestSignedInt>(a) < static_cast<LargestSignedInt>(b);
    }

    // Both types are unsigned.
    return static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<LargestSignedInt>::type>(a) < static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<LargestSignedInt>::type>(b);
}
```